# Make A UISearch Bar in iOS

Tags: ios, uisearchbar

I have this code:

```
for (NSIndexPath *indexPath in tableView.indexPathsForSelectedRows) { 
[tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:NO]; 
}
```

I have a search bar that filters out search objects and puts a check mark on the cell when you click it. However, if you search and click on the first cell, it checks it off. But if you delete the search text, the check mark shows up on the first cell, not the one that I checked off. Here is a video showing this: 
https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B1Of4oDADQCQZkF0aGdhdmF0VjA/edit
Where do I put the code above in the code below so that the checkmark stays with the selected cell?

```
#import "MSAddFriendsViewController.h"


@interface MSAddFriendsViewController ()

@end

@implementation MSAddFriendsViewController




- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
PFQuery *query = [PFUser query];
[query orderByAscending:@"username"];
[query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {
    if (error) {
        NSLog(@"Error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);

    }
    else {
        self.allUsers = objects;
        [self.tableView reloadData];
    }
}];

self.currentUser = [PFUser currentUser];


self.searchUsers.delegate = self;



}


- (void)searchBar:(UISearchBar *)searchBar textDidChange:(NSString *)searchText {
if (searchText.length == 0) {
    self.userResults = nil;
    [self.tableView reloadData];
    return ;
}
self.userResults = [NSMutableArray array];
for (PFUser *user in self.allUsers)  {
    if ([user.username rangeOfString:searchText
                          options:(NSAnchoredSearch |   NSCaseInsensitiveSearch)].location == 0) {
        [self.userResults addObject:user];
    }
}
[self.tableView reloadData];

}



#pragma mark - Table view data source

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{

// Return the number of sections.
return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:  (NSInteger)section
{

if (self.userResults != nil) {
    return [self.userResults count];
}
// Return the number of rows in the section.
return [self.allUsers count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];




PFUser *user;
if (self.userResults != nil) {
    user = [self.userResults objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
} else {
    user = [self.allUsers objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
}
cell.textLabel.text = user.username;





return cell;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
[self.tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:NO];
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
PFRelation *friendsRelation = [self.currentUser relationforKey:@"friendsRelation"];
PFUser *user = [self.allUsers objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
[friendsRelation addObject:user];
[self.currentUser saveInBackgroundWithBlock:^(BOOL succeeded, NSError *error) {
    if (error) {
        NSLog(@"Error %@ %@", error, [error userInfo]);

    }    }];



}


@end
```

Can someone please correct the code above?

Answer (score 1):

The first block of code just deselects all of the selected rows.  This isn't the solution to your problem.  There are a few fundamental issues with your code in general that need correcting...

First off -- you need to keep an array of the selected cells, indexed as the full (non-searching) table is indexed. For example, if there's text in the search bar and the first row is selected, your selected cell array should also indicate the selection boolean of the preceding and following rows not currently visible, and do so all in order.

Secondly -- you need to explicitly set the checkmarks in your cells' accessory views during your cellForRowAtIndexPath: method in order to indicate your selected cells.  The only reason that you have a checkmark in the first cell after the search bar is cleared and the table's reloaded is because the cell's being reused (i.e. [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath]).

By fixing these first and second issues, you should be off to a good start... When you're not searching, the selected cell array should contain the appropriate selection booleans for all the cells in proper order; and when you are searching, you have to filter the selected cell array in just the same way you'd filter your table based on the search text.  And instead of adding checkmarks during didSelectRowAtIndexPath:, you would be better off just indicating that the cell is selected in the selected cell array then reloading table to display the appropriate checkmark.

Comment: Hey sorry, that's a lot of code to write out and I don't have time to write it for you, but if you take some time to work out the instructions I gave you, I promise you'll be headed in the right direction.

Comment: @MicahKE - Can you Please Share code for Same Problem i am stuck in it from 2 days

Comment: @AppoorvaFaldu If you write a new question with your code, I can try to answer it for you.